# Linux (Pop_OS) Deleted File Without Proper Permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, rm

The other day I was doing some clean up and decided to delete a log file that I had stuck in my development environment, and when I did, I started to think the permissions should not have let me, I shouldn't have had permission. I don't need the file, but why did it let me?  Here's the before and after:

```
jim@jim-pop-os:~/development/apps/apoxeia/log$ ls -altr
total 441800  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jim  jim          0 Jan 25  2020 .gitkeep  
-rw-r--r--  1 jim  jim          0 Jan 25  2020 bullet.log  
drwxr-xr-x  2 jim  jim       4096 Apr  9 22:13 .  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    759153 Apr 20 08:31 production.log  
-rw-r--r--  1 jim  jim    1208297 May  3 18:03 development.log  
-rw-rw-r--  1 jim  jim  449190680 May  6 08:07 test.log  
drwxr-xr-x 25 jim  jim       4096 May  6 08:14 ..  
-rw-rw-r--  1 jim  jim    1214644 May  6 08:41 capistrano.log  
jim@jim-pop-os:~/development/apps/apoxeia/log$ rm production.log   
rm: remove write-protected regular file 'production.log'? y  
jim@jim-pop-os:~/development/apps/apoxeia/log$ ls -altr  
total 441052  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jim jim         0 Jan 25  2020 .gitkeep  
-rw-r--r--  1 jim jim         0 Jan 25  2020 bullet.log  
-rw-r--r--  1 jim jim   1208297 May  3 18:03 development.log  
-rw-rw-r--  1 jim jim 449190680 May  6 08:07 test.log  
drwxr-xr-x 25 jim jim      4096 May  6 08:14 ..  
-rw-rw-r--  1 jim jim   1214644 May  6 08:41 capistrano.log  
drwxr-xr-x  2 jim jim      4096 May  6 21:14 .  
jim@jim-pop-os:~/development/apps/apoxeia/log$
```

Note that the file production.log had write permissions only for root, but I deleted it, WITHOUT root permissions.

How did that happen?  [Sorry about the formatting.  Looked at the tips, but still didn't see a better option.]

Answer (score 5):

Deleting a file doesn't write to it – it only writes to the parent directory, where you already have the `w` and `x` permissions.

(Linux doesn't really have a "delete a file" system call – it only has an *unlink* call which works by removing a directory entry that points to the file... and if that was the last pointer, then the actual file gets garbage-collected. It's the opposite of *link* which creates hardlinks by adding directory entries.)

Comment: Wow!  In 21 years of using Linux, I never knew this!  So anyone who has write access to the parent directory can delete a file, regardless of the permission on the file itself?! Glad I learned this.  Mostly I use Linux on single user systems.

Comment: Yes, unless the directory has the "sticky" (+t) permission bit, like /tmp, in which case only the file's owner (or the directory's owner) is allowed to delete it regardless of permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if I knew this at some point and just forgot.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, thanks for reformatting the 'ls' output.  At the risk of continuing to demonstrate the depth of my ignorance, how did you do that?

Comment: I clicked the "Code sample" button. StackOverflow uses Markdown similar to that of GitHub; you can use either 4-space indents, or three backticks  \`\`\`, or in some cases `<pre>`.

Comment: @codenoob one case when you won't be able to remove a file from a directory you have full access to is when the file has _immutable_ attribute set. See [chattr(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) and [lsattr(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html) for information on how to change and view attributes.